# loading an array of structs with arrays onto cuda

Tags: struct, cuda

I'm trying to create a struct of arrays with arrays inside and load them onto the GPU.  I think I followed the steps to do this correctly.

1. Create a struct on the CPU using malloc.
2. `cudamalloc` the arrays to the struct.
3. Create a struct on the GPU using cudamalloc
4. Copy the CPU struct onto the GPU struct.

When I run this code, it will correctly work as long as I don't change the value `p[i].c[0]` in the kernel function.  If I delete the line `p[i].c[0] = 3.3;` then it outputs the expected results.  When I leave it as is, it outputs random numbers for all of the values. I would like to be able to update the values in the array using the kernel function.

What could be wrong?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <vector>
#include <sys/time.h>

    float cData[]
                {
                        1,
                        2,
                        3,
                        4,
                        5,
                        6,
                        7,
                        8,
                        9,
                        10,
                        11,
                        12,
                        13,
                        14,
                        15,
                        16
                };
    float dData[]
                {
                        1,
                        2,
                        3,
                        4,
                        5,
                        6,
                        7,
                        8,
                        9,
                        10,
                        11,
                        12,
                        13,
                        14,
                        15,
                        16
                };

    typedef struct
            {
                float a, b;
                float* c;
                float* d;
            } point;

__global__ void testKernel(point *p){
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    p[i].a = 1.1;
    p[i].b = 2.2;
    p[i].c[0] = 3.3;
}

void checkerror(cudaError_t error, char* descrp){
    if (error != 0){

        printf("%s error code: %d \n", descrp, error);
    }

}

extern "C" int main()
{
    printf("starting gpuCode\n");
    int *dev_a;
            // set number of points
        int numPoints    = 16,
            gpuBlockSize = 4,
            pointSize    = sizeof(point),
            numBytes     = numPoints * pointSize,
            gpuGridSize  = numPoints / gpuBlockSize;
    cudaError_t err = cudaSuccess;
    printf("initialized variables\n");
            // allocate memory
        point *cpuPointArray,
              *gpuPointArray,
              *outPointArray;
        cpuPointArray = (point*)malloc(numBytes);  //create the cpuPointArray struct on the cpu
        outPointArray = (point*)malloc(numBytes);  //create the outPointArray struct on the cpu
        printf("load cpuPointArray struct with default values\n");

        for (int k=0; k<16; k++){
            err = cudaMalloc( (void**)&cpuPointArray[k].c, 16*sizeof(float) );
            checkerror(err, "assigning cuda pointer c");
            err = cudaMalloc( (void**)&cpuPointArray[k].d, 16*sizeof(float) );
            checkerror(err, "assigning cuda pointer d");
            cpuPointArray[k].a = 16;
            cpuPointArray[k].b = 16;
        }


        for (int k=0; k<16; k++){
            printf("top loop %d\n", k);
            err = cudaMemcpy(cpuPointArray[k].c, cData, 16*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
            printf("after cdata\n");
            checkerror(err, "copying cdata to gpu array c" );
            err = cudaMemcpy(cpuPointArray[k].d, dData, 16*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
            printf("after ddata\n");
            checkerror(err, "copying ddata to gpu array d");
            printf("bottom of loop %d\n", k);
        }

        err = cudaMalloc((void**)&gpuPointArray, numBytes);  //allocate memory on the gpu for the cpu point array
        checkerror(err, "allocating memory for gpuPointArray");
        err = cudaMemcpy(gpuPointArray,cpuPointArray,sizeof(cpuPointArray), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); //copy the cpu point array onto the gpu
        checkerror(err, "copying cpuPointArray to gpuPointArray");

        printf("loaded the struct into the kernel\n");

        for(int i = 0; i < numPoints; ++i)
                {
                    printf("point.a: %f, point.b: %f ************************\n",cpuPointArray[i].a,cpuPointArray[i].b);

                        printf("cuda mem location point.c: %d point.d: %d\n",&cpuPointArray[i].c, &cpuPointArray[i].d);

                }

            // launch kernel
        testKernel<<<gpuGridSize,gpuBlockSize>>>(gpuPointArray);

        printf("returned the struct from the kernel\n");
        err = cudaMemcpy(outPointArray,gpuPointArray,numBytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        checkerror(err, "copying gpuPointArray to cpuPointArray");
        printf("after gpu copy to cpu\n");
        for (int k=0; k<16; k++){
            printf("creating memory on cpu for array c\n");
            outPointArray[k].c = (float*)malloc(16*sizeof(float));
            printf("creating memory on cpu for array d\n");
            outPointArray[k].d = (float*)malloc(16*sizeof(float));
            printf("copying memory values onto cpu array c\n");
            err = cudaMemcpy(outPointArray[k].c, cpuPointArray[k].c, 16*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
            checkerror(err, "copy array c from gpu to cpu");
            printf("copying memory values onto cpu array c\n");
            err = cudaMemcpy(outPointArray[k].d, cpuPointArray[k].d, 16*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
            checkerror(err, "copy array d from gpu to cpu");
            printf("bottom of loop %d\n", k);
        }

            // retrieve the results

        printf("testKernel results:\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < numPoints; ++i)
        {
            printf("point.a: %f, point.b: %f ************************\n",outPointArray[i].a,outPointArray[i].b);
            for (int j=0; j<16; j++){
                printf("point.c: %f point.d: %f\n",outPointArray[i].c[j], outPointArray[i].d[j]);
            }
        }

            // deallocate memory
        free(cpuPointArray);
        cudaFree(gpuPointArray);

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you might be copying your array of structs to the device incorrectly. Try changing:

```
err = cudaMemcpy(gpuPointArray,cpuPointArray,sizeof(cpuPointArray), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

to be

```
err = cudaMemcpy(gpuPointArray,cpuPointArray,numBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Because cpuPointArray has type point*, sizeof(cpuPointArray) will actually return the size of a pointer on your machine. What you want is the size of the full array of structs. In fact, it even looks like you did it correctly when copying back from the device with:

```
err = cudaMemcpy(outPointArray,gpuPointArray,numBytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

Hope that helps!